# Exclude Spring Boot logs

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, log4j

I'm trying to configure my `log4j2` logger to write logs INFO to file, but there are 20+ logs from Spring Boot, which i don't need.
My `pom.xml`

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.7</version>
</dependency>
```

`log4j.properties`

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=mylogs.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

`MailService.class`

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class MailService {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MailService.class);

    void sendMail() {
            logger.trace("Email sent!!");
            logger.debug("Email sent!!");
            logger.info("Email sent!!");
            logger.warn("Email sent!!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add in your `applcation.properties`:

```
logging.level.org.springframework=OFF

logging.level.root=OFF
```

But watch out, I'm not sure it's the best solution.

Comment: so try add it  pls :
log4j.category.org.springframework = ERROR

Comment: Yes, it works, but not enough( I turned off hibernate and spring logs, but there are 8 another logs(

Answer (score 0):

You need to add properties to disable logs for specific module.
`log4j2.properties` should contain below prop to hide glassfish logs. You can make appropriate changes to match your requirement.

```
logger.glassfish.name = org.glassfish
logger.glassfish.level = off
```